# Extracting values in one csv column based on the value of another

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a .csv file I'm extracting data from. This file has four columns, `['time', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange']` .

There are 100 rows for each of these columns. I wish to extract the data from the banana column and insert it into a dataframe, provided that the value in the time column is non-zero. Note: After time, t, the values in the time column go back to zero and I don't wish to extract these rows.

I would like to extract the time column, and use this as column names in my dataframe, then have the banana values as a row in my dataframe.

The reason I wish to put this into a dataframe is I have several .csv files I'm wishing to extract data from. I have a dataframe already composed with a column comprising of the paths to each of there .csvs

The code I am using to extract the banana column is:

```
for i, p in enumerate(df['path']):
    if re.match(r".*\.L.*", p):
        df = pd.read_csv(p, index_col=False, sep='\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+', comment='#', names=['time', 'apple', 'banana',  'orange',  'pear'], usecols=[1])
        df.iloc[i, 3:] = df['apple'].values
```

This however, doesn't give the column names as I wish and will extract all of the rows of the csv, not only the rows with a non-zero time value.

Comment: Could you please clarify the following:  Should the output be a DataFrame with columns `time` and `banana`?  Or should be output be a DataFrame where the `time` values are column names and the `banana` values are in the first row?

Comment: Apologise for the lack of clarity.  I want the column names to be the time. I wish the banana data to go in the same row as the path the csv is in df['path'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have your dataframe called `df`. You can select the specific rows you want like;

```
sub_df = df[['time', 'banana']][df['time'] > 0]
```

Where `['time', 'banana']` is a list of the rows in the dataframe you are choosing and `df['time'] > 0` is a filter to only use rows where the time is greater than zero.

Then you can pivot it like,

```
df_pivot = sub_df.pivot(columns='time', values='banana')
```

Here you make the columns your times and their values banana.

You could also do this in one row like

```
df_pivot = df[['time', 'banana']][df['time'] > 0].pivot(columns='time', values='banana')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent answer.